# Hyper-V 2016 DDA issue: a VM boot fails when a drive is connected to an opposite NUMA node

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, ubuntu-16.04, numa, hyper-v-server-2016

Brief description: the host is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Build 14393 (UEFI) running Hyper-V role. SR-IOV and Intel VT are enabled. 4x Intel® Optane ™ SSD 900P 280GB PCIe NVMe 3.0 drives are connected to the host. To check DDA support, I execute [the PowerShell script](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/live/hyperv-tools/DiscreteDeviceAssignment/SurveyDDA.ps1) that returns OK, DDA is supported. Ubuntu Server 16.04 (gen 2) VM is deployed. All [required packages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v) were installed to the VM. Then, I've connected those 4x Optane SSDs to the Ubuntu Server VM [via DDA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/deploying-storage-devices-using-dda). After that, additional settings `-LowMemoryMappedIoSpace 1Gb -HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 4Gb` were applied. So, VM has passthrough connected 4x NVMe drives. The reboot/shutdown/power-on the Ubuntu VM works without a problem. Also, there are no issues with the connectivity between drives and VM.

The problem case: when the Windows Server host reboots, the boot of Ubuntu Server VM fails.

[image: a VM boot error]

[image: the error event ID]

From what I found, I assume a NUMA node configuration is the problem. The VM's boot fails because of NVMe SSDs that are connected to another NUMA. For the information, 2x SSD drives are connected to # 0 NUMA node and another 2x SSDs have the connection to # 1 NUMA one.

[image]

So VM's boot runs on the # 1 NUMA node and fails. The VM boots only when NVMe SSDs running on # 0 NUMA are disconnected.